# Is there a way in javascript to see if a variable has a timeout assigned to it?

Tags: javascript, timeout

I'm currently using a loop that repeats itself every few milliseconds in my program. In this loop, it checks for a certain input, and if received, cancels another timeout. Essentially:

```
if (inputreceived && secondTimerRunning)
{
   timerID2.clearTimeout();
   secondTimerRunning = false;
}
```

However, those lines cause my loop to terminate. From what I can tell, it's because I am trying to clear a Timeout that doesn't exist. Is there a way to prevent this, or am I using Timeouts wrong?

Comment: isn't the syntax clearTimeout(timerID2)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for `clearTimeout()` is;

```
clearTimeout(timerID2);
```

It is a function which accepts the ID returned by `setTimeout()`; i.e. you don't call it *on* the ID returned.

`clearTimeout` will not error if the value you pass to it is not a valid ID.

For more info, see the [documentation for `clearTimeout()` on MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout).

Answer (score 2):

Use `clearTimeout(timerID2)` instead, timeouts are represented by a number identifier and clearTimeout is a global function that can be called directly.